# Remove UIView from SKScene in another file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, sprite-kit

I have my `GameViewController.swift` with SKView.

In `GameScene.swift` I created UIView that covers my Scene.
[image]

`var overlayView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)`
When I tap on screen (`touchesBegan`) `overlayView.isHidden = true`
and when `touchesEnded` `overlayView.isHidden = false`.
But I have a problem. When I need to change something (In another ViewController) and go back to Scene overlayView doesn't hide when I tap on screen. (New overlayView, which appeared after the scene was reloaded, cover previous overlayView. And previous overlayView "covers" my Scene)

```
//GameScene.swift 
var overlayView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

func closeView() {
        overlayView.removeFromSuperview()
        print("hidden")
    }


//GameViewController.swift
@IBOutlet var tandmScene: SKView!


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "TandM") {
        scene.size = self.view.frame.size
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        tandmScene.presentScene(scene)
    }
    tandmScene.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    tandmScene.showsFPS = true
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
GameScene().closeView()
}
```

My `overlayView.removeFromSuperview()` isn't working. If I put `if let scene = ...` in viewDidLoad my scene does not change.

Comment: in `viewWillDisappear` change `GameScene().closeView()` to `self.closeView()` to fix one issue.

Comment: @Kamran closeView() is a GameScene method, not GameViewController

Comment: Ok, then where is the `GameScene` reference in `GameViewController`. Use that. when you do `GameScene()`, it creates a new object of `GameScene` so it will not call the closeView of the other object that was created to add the overlay view.

Comment: @Kamran Where I need to create reference? If `let tandm = TandMScene()` is a class variable I have `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Notification Center`

```
//GameScene.swift
override func sceneDidLoad() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.init("close"), object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] (notification) in
            self?.closeView()
        }
...
}

//GameViewController.swift
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.init("close"), object: nil)
...
}
```